# Subdomain login.xyz.com not changing even after logging in

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, subdomain, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have used subdomain for my website eg login.xyz.comand it should be pointing toward xyz.com/login. This thing works fine but the issue is this login.xyz.com works me for every page. Even if i am logged in inside the webste the login.xyz.com becomes login.xyz.com/abc. How can i resolve this issue.

This is the below code which I have used :

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name login.xyz.com.com;
  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost.com/login;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. What you want to achieve? In the `nginx` config which you have provided, it will always redirect `login.xyz.com.com` to `/`.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri My current website is xyz.com and the login page for that website is xyz.com/login. And once I log in it, the page changes to xyz.com/jobs or anything. So we wanted to convert xyz.com/login to login.xyz.com and after I log in it should go to xyz.com/jobs as earlier but currently with the above configuration, after logging in it send me to login.xyz.com/jobs. The Subdomain(Login.x.x) is always there with the main domain. I just want it to be for a single page and not for the whole time. I hope this will help.

Comment: You could redirect `login.xyz.com` to `xyz.com/login` first, rather than using `proxy_pass`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you guide how can I add that in the same. I am new to coding and I am not much aware of it.  WIll the below config work? 

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name login.xyz.com.com;
  location / {
      redirect xyz.com/login;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}

Comment: `location / { return 301 http://example.com/login; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Using that it directly redirects me to my xyz.com/login. I want that it should show login.xyz.com and once I login then it should take to the page I am( eg xyz.com/jobs). I have added the above code which you gave.